# Issues setting DTM Data Element by either returning value or setting data element directly

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-analytics

Not sure why I can't update the data element in DTM. I'm trying to add a listener and update the "custom link name" whenever an element with the HTML5 custom attribute exists and is clicked. I haven't had any luck and don't know what I'm doing wrong?

```
function addEvent(el, ev, fn, uc) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(ev, fn, uc);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) { // IE8-
        el.attachEvent('on'+ev, fn);
    }
}

addEvent(document, 'click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var customLinkName = target.getAttribute("data-analytics-tracking-name");

    if(customLinkName){
      //return customLinkName;
      _satellite.setVar("custom link name", customLinkName); 
    }

}, false);
```

When ever I check the value of the data element I get the default value that was set in the UI. Any idea how I make the data element update every time a qualifying element is clicked? this code runs as custom script for the data element in DTM, it is not being run as an event.

Comment: my suspicion is that the target element does not have that `data-analytics-tracking-name` attribute. IOW it may not be the immediate element being clicked.  `console.log(target)` to verify what element is the click event is actually triggering on.

Comment: Hi Crayon.. yes the attribute is being read and I can output the value to the console.

Comment: It's my understanding that _satellite.setVar will set custom variables in _satellite.data.customVars. _satellite.getVar will execute a data element first and then fail over to retrieving a value from customVars. Try either using a key that is not the same. If you need it as a data element, use a custom script to retrieve the value of the customVar. Sounds hacky but it's worked for me.

Comment: BrettAHale you are correct. I just found out from a friend that to make this work, whatever data element name I use in the _satellite.setVar function, ensure that it does not exist as a pre-defined data element. It will not allow you to overwrite the definition with the _satellite.setVar function. So I can just add a custom condition to the event rule to dynamically get the value from this attribute that was listening for the attribute click.